# NP class : Why polynomial length outputs?

Tags: algorithm, np-complete, np

For a problem to qualify for the NP class :

1. The solution to the problem must have a polynomial output length ,and
2. The solution must be verifiable in polynomial time .

What is the significance of the polynomial output length ?

PS : I think that polynomial output length is a necessary pre-condition for the output to be verifiable in polynomial time. (But then just saying that solutions can be verified in polynomial time will still be sufficient.)

Comment: This is not the standard definition for NP. In fact, NP is for *decision problems* (yes/no) where you can easily have output of length 1 bit. There are two equivalent definitions for NP I am aware of, none have constraints of the input size - because it really is constant.

Comment: If the output length is not polynomial, how can you output it in polynomial time?

Comment: This definition of NP completeness was taught by Professor roughgarden of stanford university in an MOOC. But, there is no such mention on wikipedia. I think professor roughgarden was teaching something wrong.

Comment: @Yu-HanLyu That is what I too am referring to . That the requirement of solutions be polynomial in length is unnecessary and redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomial length imposition is because you are modeling the machine as a universal turing machine.

In thi case, the output "tape" would have to be of polynomial length.

It is not because you are using a modern language and expecting polynomial length results.

Comment: And in the RAM model it wouldn't be? I don't understand you answer (and the question uses a definition I never have seen before)

Comment: The problem was that the question was a bit ill-stated.  For example, you could have an NP-complete algorithm that spits out one character.  It's in the context of a UTM and the input and output tape that a "polynomial length result" makes sense.  This should have been specified in the question.  Abstractly, there is no difference, but I was trying to clarify and answer the question.